# Aligning buttons in html

Tags: tags, alignment, row

I have code that uses the `<ul>` and the anchor tags, I have put: `<br> <br />`

`<center>` (without some spaces.....) above it, and this: '''' below it. But I still get 3 rows I have in total 5 buttons, 4 that change when you hover over them and one dropdown menu in the middle. But I need them to be all on one level. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <button>Button-1</button><button>Button-2</button>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <button>Button-3</button><button>Button-4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I edit the code so I have 2 buttons that change image files than the dropdown with the custom image and than another 2 buttons like the first 2

Comment: Didn't get your Question